# SQL Server 2008 - error 241

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I have an error in my stored procedure on SQL Server 2008.

I need to do stuff and insert data in my table only if the current element doesn't already exist.

So I create a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[upload_bank_file] 
    @date varchar(10), 
    @date_valeur varchar(10), 
    @libelle varchar(255), 
    @mode varchar(10), 
    @code varchar(10), 
    @date_effet varchar(10), 
    @debit float, 
    @credit float
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

print @credit;
IF Not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.bank_import WHERE dbo.bank_import.Libelle = @libelle)
    --DROP PROCEDURE upload_bank_file; 
Begin 
    IF (SUBSTRING(@date_effet, 4, 2) LIKE '01' AND SUBSTRING(@date, 1, 2) LIKE '12')
        SET @date_effet = CONVERT(varchar, (CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@date, 7, 2)) + 1)) + '-' + @date_effet;
    ELSE
        SET @date_effet = SUBSTRING(@date, 7, 2) + '-' + @date_effet;

    insert into dbo.bank_import ([Date], [Date_Valeur], [Libelle], [Mode], [Code], [Date_Effet], [Debit], [Credit])
    VALUES (CONVERT(datetime, @date, 120), CONVERT(datetime, @date_valeur, 120), @libelle, @mode, @code, CONVERT(datetime, @date_effet, 120), @debit, @credit);
    END
END
```

When I test it via my php moulinette (to automatize file parsing and call to the stored procedure), I got the following error :

> [0] => 22007
>   [SQLSTATE] => 22007
>   [1] => 241
>   [code] => 241
>   [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Échec de la conversion de la date et/ou de l'heure à partir d'une chaîne de caractères.
>   [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Échec de la conversion de la date et/ou de l'heure à partir d'une chaîne de caractères.

I'm passing date to the stored procedure via `varchar`, in `yyyy/mm/dd` format, and `mm/dd` format for `@date` parameter.

The SQL Server Management Studio, when I do

```
EXEC upload_bank_file 'with', 'fake', 'parameters' ...
```

is locating the error on the line 20 of my stored procedure, which is the line where I do my "If Exists ( Select ... )", only when my libelle didn't exists in the table.

I googled this error several times, but i have found nothing useful. I passed my date on `yyyy/mm/dd` format and I have specify the `SET DATEFORMAT ymd` flag to my stored procedure, but my problem remains.

If someone have any idea to help me, I will be grateful!

(English is not my mother tongue, please excuse me for the errors ...)

Thanks !

Comment: Does anything change if you call the stored procedure directly? Meaning not from php but a sql console.

Comment: If you have dates - you should definitely use `DATETIME2(n)` or just `DATE` (if time isn't important) in your code! Don't use `Varchar` for dates, if ever possible!!

Comment: I suspect this is the problem: "I'm passing  **mm/dd** format for @date parameter." - a Date in Sql Server has a year, it just doesn't have a time. so this will have to be `yyyy/mm/dd` as well.

Comment: Paul, anything change when I called directly my stored procedure, I've got the same error.

Comment: Is dbo.bank_import.libelle the same datatype as @libelle?

Comment: Stuart, I precise what I pass mm/dd, but under varchar variable, because I haven't succeed to send datetime parameter from my php script

Comment: Dave, Yes, there are varchar(255) in parameters and into the table

Answer (score 2):

> *I'm passing date to the stored procedure via varchar, in yyyy/mm/dd*
>   *format, and **mm/dd format for @date parameter**.*

As you're passsing @date as `mm/dd` it's this part that fails:

```
CONVERT(datetime, @date, 120)
```

You're effectively then calling this for today (16th July):

```
select CONVERT(datetime, '07/16', 120)
```

Which fails with error 241, "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

If you pass in the year as well, it will succeed:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, '2014/07/16', 120)
```

if you then need to just extract the day and month values, use [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Comment: Thanks to everybody, I will investigate with your advices.

Just another question : If my stored procedure failed on CONVERT statement, why my sql debogguer highlight the SELECT statement's line and says "your error comes from here" ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible